# Android's AddArc not working as expected

Tags: c#, android, math, xamarin, geometry

I'm having trouble rendering an arc correctly on Android. I suspect my math is failing me here, but I've checked and re-checked and can't spot the problem.

Consider the following:

[image: Geometry rendering]

Where:

- `R` is the bounding rectangle for the ellipse
- `O` is the origin of the ellipse
- `a` is the x radius of the ellipse
- `b` is the y radius of the ellipse
- `P1` is the first point on the ellipse
- `P2` is the second point on the ellipse

I want the arc to extend between P1 and P2, but as you can see, it starts early and ends late.

Once I have determined the bounding rectangle for the ellipse (which is correct), I first draw some debug info:

```
// highlight each important point
path.AddCircle(P1.X, P1.Y, 3, Graphics.Path.Direction.Cw);
path.AddCircle(P2.X, P2.Y, 3, Graphics.Path.Direction.Cw);
path.AddCircle(O.X, O.Y, 3, Graphics.Path.Direction.Cw);

// draw bounding rectangle
path.AddRect(rect, Graphics.Path.Direction.Cw);

// draw in ellipse radii (a and b)
path.MoveTo(O.X, O.Y);
path.RLineTo(radius.Width, 0);
path.MoveTo(O.X, O.Y);
path.RLineTo(0, radius.Height);
```

In the specific example depicted above, these are the values I am working with  (I'll be rounding all values a bit for sake of clarity):

```
O = (644, 850.154)
P1 = (528.08, 1030.4)
P2 = (759.92, 1030.4)
R = (322, 656.954, 644, 386.4)
```

So far, so good. Everything above is right where it should be. Next, I calculate normalized vectors from `O` to both `P1` and `P2`:

```
var P1Vec = (P1 - O).Normalize();
var P2Vec = (P2 - O).Normalize();
```

These come out as:

```
P1Vec = (-0.541, 0.841)
P2Vec = (0.541, 0.841)
```

To be sure these were correct, I added some more debug graphics:

```
path.MoveTo(O.X, O.Y);
var end = startVec * 400;
path.RLineTo(end.X, end.Y);
path.MoveTo(O.X, O.Y);
end = endVec * 400;
path.RLineTo(end.X, end.Y);
```

As you can see from the image, these lines cut *exactly* through `P1` and `P2`, just as you'd expect.

So the next step is to figure out angles, since that is what Android's `AddArc` method expects:

```
var P1VecDot = Point.UnitX.Dot(P1Vec);
var P2VecDot = Point.UnitX.Dot(P2Vec);

var P1Acos = Math.Acos(P1VecDot);
var P2Acos = Math.Acos(P2VecDot);

var P1Angle = P1Acos.ToDegrees();
var P2Angle = P2Acos.ToDegrees();
```

The values I get here are:

```
P1VecDot = -0.541
P2VecDot = 0.541
P1Acos = 2.142
P2Acos = 0.999
P1Angle = 122.745
P2Angle = 57.254
```

The span between those angles is about 65°, which feels about right. So, `P1Angle` is our starting angle, so I need only calculate the sweep and then draw the arc:

```
var sweepAngle = P2Angle - P1Angle;
path.AddArc(R, startAngle, sweepAngle);
```

But the arc drawn doesn't look right.

I am certain this has to do with drawing an elliptical arc, as opposed to a circular, because if I make the arc circular then everything works. I get the sense that I need to project the points on the ellipse onto equivalent points on the circle and use those points to calculate angles, but I've not clicked on how to do this yet.

Any thoughts on how to fix?

**UPDATE**: I've figured out what's going on here, and it's entirely undocumented behavior as far as I can tell. I'll clean up my code over the weekend and post an answer (actually, might do a blog post on this one).

Comment: Can you maybe compare with `canvas.DrawArc` I am using that, which seems to work. Your math seems similar to mine, except I subtract 90, because I want to start drawing at 12 o'clock.

Comment: @Cheesbaron Where is yours? Also, I have updated question with some further thoughts.